# Shortening code by exploiting symmetry among multiple type class instances

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies, template-haskell

## Context

I'm writing a Haskell module that represents SI prefixes:

```
module Unit.SI.Prefix where
```

Each SI prefix has a corresponding data type:

```
data Kilo = Kilo deriving Show
data Mega = Mega deriving Show
data Giga = Giga deriving Show
data Tera = Tera deriving Show

-- remaining prefixes omitted for brevity
```

## Problem

I would like to write a function that, when applied with two SI prefixes, determines **statically** which of the two prefixes is **smaller**. For example:

```
-- should compile:
test1 = let Kilo = smaller Kilo Giga in ()
test2 = let Kilo = smaller Giga Kilo in ()

-- should fail to compile:
test3 = let Giga = smaller Kilo Giga in ()
test4 = let Giga = smaller Giga Kilo in ()
```

## Initial Solution

Here's a solution that uses a type class together with a functional dependency:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}                                                                                         
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Smaller a b c | a b -> c where smaller :: a -> b -> c

instance Smaller Kilo Kilo Kilo where smaller Kilo Kilo = Kilo
instance Smaller Kilo Mega Kilo where smaller Kilo Mega = Kilo
instance Smaller Kilo Giga Kilo where smaller Kilo Giga = Kilo
instance Smaller Kilo Tera Kilo where smaller Kilo Tera = Kilo

instance Smaller Mega Kilo Kilo where smaller Mega Kilo = Kilo
instance Smaller Mega Mega Mega where smaller Mega Mega = Mega
instance Smaller Mega Giga Mega where smaller Mega Giga = Mega
instance Smaller Mega Tera Mega where smaller Mega Tera = Mega

instance Smaller Giga Kilo Kilo where smaller Giga Kilo = Kilo
instance Smaller Giga Mega Mega where smaller Giga Mega = Mega
instance Smaller Giga Giga Giga where smaller Giga Giga = Giga
instance Smaller Giga Tera Giga where smaller Giga Tera = Giga

instance Smaller Tera Kilo Kilo where smaller Tera Kilo = Kilo
instance Smaller Tera Mega Mega where smaller Tera Mega = Mega
instance Smaller Tera Giga Giga where smaller Tera Giga = Giga
instance Smaller Tera Tera Tera where smaller Tera Tera = Tera
```

The above solution appears to solve the problem correctly, however it has a downside: the number of type class instances is **quadratic** w.r.t. the number of types.

## Question

Is there any way to reduce the number of type class instances to be **linear** w.r.t. the number of types, perhaps by exploiting symmetry?

It may be that it's more appropriate to use Template Haskell here, in which case, feel free to suggest that as a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be a stupid question, by why not `data Prefix = Kilo | Mega | Giga | Tera...` ?

Comment: @Landei: I assume the goal is to distinguish them by type to ensure more thoroughly that there's no way to mix them up. On the other hand, GADTs or phantom types might make sense here.

Comment: @Landei: That's a fair question. My reason for using separate data types is that I wish to check at compile time that a given prefix (for example: Kilo) is not being used in a context that expects a different prefix (for example: Mega). I'd like to use such prefixes to implement type-safe memory arithmetic. Using the type "data (Integral a, Unit b) => Memory a b = Memory a b)", I can do the right thing if someone attempts to (for example) add a "Memory Int64 KiB" to a "Memory Int64 MiB".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could probably be argued that TH is more appropriate in cases like this. That said, I'll do it with types anyhow.

The problem here is that everything is *too discrete*. You can't iterate through the prefixes to find the right one, and you're not expressing the transitivity of the ordering you want. We can solve it by either route.

For a recursive solution, we first create natural numbers and boolean values at the type level:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data No = No deriving (Show)
data Yes = Yes deriving (Show)

newtype S nat = Succ nat deriving (Show)
data Z = Zero deriving (Show)

type Zero  = Z
type One   = S Zero
type Two   = S One
type Three = S Two
```

A bit of simple arithmetic:

```
type family Plus x y :: *
type instance Plus x Z = x
type instance Plus Z y = y
type instance Plus (S x) (S y) = S (S (Plus x y))

type family Times x y :: *
type instance Times x Z = Z
type instance Times x (S y) = Plus x (Times y x)
```

A "less than or equal to" predicate, and a simple conditional function:

```
type family IsLTE n m :: *
type instance IsLTE Z Z = Yes
type instance IsLTE (S m) Z = No
type instance IsLTE Z (S n) = Yes
type instance IsLTE (S m) (S n) = IsLTE m n

type family IfThenElse b t e :: *
type instance IfThenElse Yes t e = t
type instance IfThenElse No t e = e
```

And conversions from the SI prefixes to the magnitude they represent:

```
type family Magnitude si :: *
type instance Magnitude Kilo = Three
type instance Magnitude Mega = Three `Times` Two
type instance Magnitude Giga = Three `Times` Three
```

...etc.

Now, to find the smaller prefix, you can do this:

```
type family Smaller x y :: *
type instance Smaller x y = IfThenElse (Magnitude x `IsLTE` Magnitude y) x y
```

Given that everything here has a one-to-one correspondence between the type and the single nullary constructor inhabiting it, this can be translated to the term level using a generic class like this:

```
class TermProxy t where term :: t
instance TermProxy No where term = No
instance TermProxy Yes where term = Yes
{- More instances here... -}

smaller :: (TermProxy a, TermProxy b) => a -> b -> Smaller a b
smaller _ _ = term
```

Filling in the details as needed.

---

The other approach involves using functional dependencies and overlapping instances to write a generic instance to fill in gaps--so you could write specific instances for Kilo < Mega, Mega < Giga, etc. and let it deduce that this implies Kilo < Giga as well.

This gets deeper into treating functional dependencies as what they are--a primitive logic programming language. If you've ever used Prolog, you should have the rough idea. In some ways this is nice, because you can let the compiler figure things out based on a more declarative approach. On the other hand it's also kind of terrible because...

- Instances are chosen without looking at constraints, only the instance head.
- There's no backtracking to search for a solution.
- To express this sort of thing you have to turn on `UndecidableInstances` because of GHC's very conservative rules about what it knows will terminate; but you then have to take care not to send the type checker into an infinite loop. For instance, it would be very easy to do that by accident given instances like `Smaller Kilo Kilo Kilo` and something like `(Smaller a s c, Smaller t b s) => Smaller a b c`--think about why.

Fundeps and overlapping instances are strictly more powerful than type families, but they're clumsier to use overall, and feel somewhat out of place compared to the more functional, recursive style the latter uses.

---

Oh, and for completeness' sake, here's a third approach: This time, we're abusing the extra power that overlapping instances gives us to implement a recursive solution directly, rather than by converting to natural numbers and using structural recursion.

First, reify the desired ordering as a type-level list:

```
data MIN = MIN deriving (Show)
data MAX = MAX deriving (Show)

infixr 0 :<
data a :< b = a :< b deriving (Show)

siPrefixOrd :: MIN :< Kilo :< Mega :< Giga :< Tera :< MAX
siPrefixOrd = MIN :< Kilo :< Mega :< Giga :< Tera :< MAX
```

Implement an *equality predicate on types*, using some overlapping shenanigans:

```
class (TypeEq' () x y b) => TypeEq x y b where typeEq :: x -> y -> b
instance (TypeEq' () x y b) => TypeEq x y b where typeEq _ _ = term

class (TermProxy b) => TypeEq' q x y b | q x y -> b
instance (b ~ Yes) => TypeEq' () x x b 
instance (b ~ No) => TypeEq' q x y b
```

The alternate "is less than" class, with the two easy cases:

```
class IsLTE a b o r | a b o -> r where
    isLTE :: a -> b -> o -> r

instance (IsLTE a b o r) => IsLTE a b (MIN :< o) r where
    isLTE a b (_ :< o) = isLTE a b o

instance (No ~ r) => IsLTE a b MAX r where
    isLTE _ _ MAX = No
```

And then the recursive case, with an auxiliary class used to defer the recursive step based on case analysis of the type-level boolean:

```
instance ( TypeEq a x isA, TypeEq b x isB
         , IsLTE' a b isA isB o r
         ) => IsLTE a b (x :< o) r where
    isLTE a b (x :< o) = isLTE' a b (typeEq a x) (typeEq b x) o

class IsLTE' a b isA isB xs r | a b isA isB xs -> r where
    isLTE' :: a -> b -> isA -> isB -> xs -> r

instance (Yes ~ r) => IsLTE' a b Yes Yes xs r where isLTE' a b _ _ _ = Yes
instance (Yes ~ r) => IsLTE' a b Yes No xs r where isLTE' a b _ _ _ = Yes
instance (No ~ r) => IsLTE' a b No Yes xs r where isLTE' a b _ _ _ = No
instance (IsLTE a b xs r) => IsLTE' a b No No xs r where
    isLTE' a b _ _ xs = isLTE a b xs
```

In essence, this takes a type-level list and two arbitrary types, then walks down the list and returns `Yes` if it finds the first type, or `No` if it finds the second type or hits the end of the list.

This is actually kind of buggy (you can see why if you think about what happens if one or both types aren't in the list), as well as prone to failing--direct recursion like this uses a context reduction stack in GHC that is very shallow, so it's easy to exhaust it and get a type-level stack overflow (ha ha, yes, the joke writes itself) instead of the answer you wanted.

Comment: Good answer, but you should probably point out that there are lots of implementations of type-level numbers etc. on Hackage.

Comment: @John L: Agreed, though the fact that there *are* lots of different implementations makes me not feel too guilty about just using my own. I was also in a hurry when writing this, alas, and I wasn't sure which existing libraries might have the operations I needed. Most of this was copy-paste from my own type hackery libraries.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: Thanks for taking the time to write this very detailed answer. It contains a lot of food for thought, and much to learn from. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can map your types to type level natural numbers and then do the comparisons using those. That should make it linear as you only have to specify one instance for each type mapping it to the corresponding number.

The [type arithmetic](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_arithmetic) page on the Haskell Wiki has some nice examples of working with type level natural numbers. It would be a good place to start.

Also note that there is already the popular package [dimensional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional) on Hackage for working with SI units in a similar way. It might be worthwhile to have a look at how this is implemented in their code.

Comment: I just realized I forgot to thank you for your comment. I know it was four years ago, but I would still like to say thanks for your help. :)